# Guaranteeing execution of pthread_cond_wait before pthread_wait_signal

Tags: c++, c, pthreads

Not sure if this question has been asked before, but how is it (or is it) guaranteed that `pthread_cond_wait` is executed before `pthread_cond_signal/broadcast`?

What happens if one thread calls `pthread_cond_wait` after the subsequent `pthread_cond_signal` was called?

Does the signal get lost?

If `pthread_cond_signal` is a blocking call (which it sounds like, from the description "at least one thread is awakened") what happens to the mutex in that blocking state? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Additionally, how is pthread_cond_broadcast executed? Is the calling thread blocked until all the threads that were waiting on that condition are awakened?

Comment: No. Neither `pthread_cond_signal` nor `pthread_cond_broadcast` block their caller.

Comment: Another question, so does call to pthread_cond_signal immediately wake up the waiting thread? The description of wait function says that the mutex is again owned by the waiting thread when the wait function returns. So now isn't the signaling thread is also owning the mutex at the same time?

Comment: `pthread_cond_wait` cannot return until the mutex is re-acquired. If the signaling thread holds the mutex while signaling, then it can control when the waiter is able to "wake up" by when it releases the mutex. If it's already released the mutex before signaling, it has no such control over the waiter's waking up; as long as no other thread has taken the mutex, the waiter can wake up immediately as soon as the signal is sent.

Comment: Awesome! That explains it a lot. Thanks for your help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does not matter whether `pthread_cond_wait` happens before or after `pthread_cond_signal`, because you only call `pthread_cond_wait` while the predicate is false, and the state on which the predicate depends cannot change while the mutex associated with the condition variable is held.

Suppose the waiter is doing something like:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(mutex);
while (!predicate(state)) pthread_cond_wait(cond, mutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(mutex);
```

In order to have a reason to signal the condition variable, the thread doing the signaling must have made some change to `state`. In order to do this without invoking undefined behavior, it must hold `mutex`, which protects `state`. However, this means either the change to `state` completed *before* the above code snippet (in which case `pthread_cond_wait` is never called because `predicate(state)` is now true), during the call to `pthread_cond_wait` (while the mutex is unlocked; in this case, the signal after changing `state` will unblock the wait), or after the end of the above code snippet (in which case it's irrelevant).

Comment: gotcha. So the state is protected by the same mutex too. So looks like the only reason you use cond_wait is to avoid polling continuously on the state of the predicate and hogging cpu cycles.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: It's not just to avoid hogging cpu cycles, but to give the threads that modify the state a chance to run. The only way you could "poll continuously" is to rapidly lock and unlock the mutex, and if you got unlucky, the thread that wants to change the state might never get the mutex.

Comment: So that brings up another question, what happens when multiple threads are waiting on the same condition and broadcast is being used? I am guessing here that those threads are woken up one by one. So what happens if the predicate changes the state while we are in the middle of waking up the threads? Is it responsibility of programmer to not let that happen? In that case how does he know that the broadcast process is complete and now it is safe to change the state of the predicate.

Comment: I guess just using a different condition variable each time will solve this problem.

Comment: I think you're imagining problems that don't exist. It's safe to change the state on which the predicate depends only when you hold the mutex that protects it, since no other thread can be inspecting or changing it while you hold the mutex. (This is of course assuming you're using the mutex correctly.)

Comment: Note that in the correct usage of a condition variable, you *always* re-check the predicate after `pthread_cond_wait` returns. You don't just assume it's true. Thus, in the case of multiple waiters and multiple signals or broadcasts, it's not a problem if the first thread that gets the mutex changes the state in such a way that the predicate is now false for the next thread. That next thread will just re-check the predicate and go back to waiting if it's false.

Comment: Yup, my concerns was that the 2nd thread now missed on the event that predicate did become true (only for a while though). But I guess if the predicate is going to change it's state a lot/quickly, we can use a separate variable to check if it the predicate ever became true and wait on that (basically use that variable as the predicate).